# Keycloak Custom message on user temporary lock

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-gatekeeper

I am using Kyecloak:4.8.0, and have enabled Brute force attack for my realm.
Now whenever user provides wrong credentials for 3 times user will be locked temporarily.

But still user will see "Invalid username/password".

According to this thread Keycloak have done this intentionally:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-5284

But still i want to show user that his account has been locked.

Is there any way to customize this message?

I tried doing this by adding message in custom keycloak theme as below:

location: themes\adminlte\login\messages\messages_en.properties

```
accountTemporarilyDisabledMessage=Account is temporarily disabled, contact admin or try again later.
```

This change is not working.

Comment: If you do this, a smart brute force detection can find all email addresses available in your system by just temporarily locking them. This is why the lock message is intentionally not added

Comment: Yes @Marcel I understand. Thank You :)

Comment: Regarding @Marcel 's comment, here is a source confirming it is intentional. https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-8013

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After going through Keycloak base code what i found is: Keycloak uses `Messages.INVALID_USER` (invalidUserMessage) from properties which is written in `AbstractFormAuthenticator` class.

This class is at the end extended by UsernamePasswordForm now to change this to custom message i Wrote Custom Authenticator (Keycloak SPI) like below

```
public class CustomUsernameFormAuthenticator extends UsernamePasswordForm {

    @Override
    protected String tempDisabledError() {
        return Messages.ACCOUNT_TEMPORARILY_DISABLED;
    }
}
```

After this deploy spi Jar in keycloak and enable it in your realm.
And we are done :)