# NoClassDefFoundError from Maven deploy when attempting to create a custom authenticator provider for Keycloak

Tags: java, maven, wildfly, keycloak

I'm implementing a Keycloak authentication provider (for Keycloak 6.0.1) which returns a message when a user is temporarily locked (like specified at
[Keycloak Custom message on user temporary lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57112945/keycloak-custom-message-on-user-temporary-lock#answer-61223715))

When I do `mvn clean install wildfly:deploy` I get :

```
[ERROR]     Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticatorFactory: Provider com.mumba.cloud.authenticator.LockedUserAuthenticatorFactory could not be instantiated
[ERROR]     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/mumba/cloud/authenticator/LockedUserAuthenticator (Module \"deployment.lockeduser-authenticator-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar\" from Service Module Loader): org/keycloak/authentication/authenticators/browser/UsernamePasswordForm"}}}}
```

I'm looking for some help on how to track down why I'm getting the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError and why Maven (or maybe it's wildfly) can't seem to find org/keycloak/authentication/authenticators/browser/UsernamePasswordForm

It isn't a compile-time error, and I believe my import statement below is correct for UsernamePasswordForm (see code below).

I also think I have correctly added the dependency (keycloak-services) to my pom.xml (see below).

I'm very new to Maven (and Java/Keycloak development), so I'm not sure where to dig to track this down.

Anyone have any pointers?

```
package com.mumba.cloud.authenticator;

import org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.UsernamePasswordForm;

public class LockedUserAuthenticator extends UsernamePasswordForm  {
    @Override
    protected String tempDisabledError() {
        return "ACCOUNT IS temporarily disabled.";
    }
}
```

My pom.xml includes :

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <keycloak-version>6.0.1</keycloak-version>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-services</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak-version}</version>
        </dependency>
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add explicit dependencies to avoid class-loading issues at runtime.
Here is what you need to add to your `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <!-- This is required since we need to add the jboss module references
                            to the resulting jar -->
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <!-- Adding explicit dependencies to avoid class-loading issues at runtime -->
                            <Dependencies>
                                <![CDATA[org.keycloak.keycloak-core,org.keycloak.keycloak-services]]></Dependencies>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

Also, add scope `provided` to you dependencies as follows:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-services</artifactId>
        <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks heaps Hasni. This worked for me. If others are having similar issues, they might find some of the information at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57778240/noclassdeffounderror-in-a-provider-jar-when-using-a-class-from-org-keycloak-auth#answer-57791073 to be helpful.